# How to change magento add to cart button based on product attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to change the add to cart button text based on my pre-order attribute, however it's not working quite as expected. Currently my code looks like this:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable() && $_product->getAttributeText('preorder') == 'Yes'): ?>                   
    <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Pre-Order') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Pre-Order') ?></span></span></button></p>
<?php elseif($_product->isSaleable() && $_product->getAttributeText('preorder') == 'No'): ?>
    <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
<?php else: ?> 
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Product Info') ?></a></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the output of: `$_product->getAttributeText('preorder')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming Preorder is a Yes/No Attribute?

if so you can use this:

isSaleable() && $_product->getPreorder()):?>

You should still be able to use your method though if you ensure the following:

You also need to go into the edit attributes section and make sure you have enabled the setting to add the attribute to the collection/object when needed.

If you're on the product view page enable:

```
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end : YES
```

If you're on the product listing page:

```
Used in Product Listing: YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas! I realized the issue was that I was using single quotes and not double quotes! Doh!

```
&& $_product->getAttributeText('preorder') == "Yes"): ?>
```